# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'drafts' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found. 1

Tags: python, django

I am getting error

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'drafts' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found. 1

I have created a button for delete view, and it is not working. whenever i am clicking on button the above error is coming.

here is the code:

in views.py

```
class DraftsView(ListView):
    model=models.NewPost
    context_object_name='newpost'

class DraftsEditView(DetailView):
    context_object_name='draft_view'
    model=models.NewPost
    template_name='blogapp/newpost_details.html'
    # pk_url_kwarg="id"

class DraftsUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields=('Author','Title','Text')
    model=models.NewPost

class DraftsDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model=models.NewPost
    context_object_name='newpost'
    success_url=reverse_lazy("blogapp:drafts")
```

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[url('about/',views.about,name='about'),
url('register/',views.register,name='register'),
url('user_login/',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
url('newpost/',views.NewPostView,name='newpost'),
url('drafts/',views.DraftsView.as_view(),name='drafts'),
path('<int:pk>',views.DraftsEditView.as_view(),name='view_draft'),
path('update/<int:pk>/',views.DraftsUpdateView.as_view(),name='update'),
path('delete/<int:pk>/',views.DraftsDeleteView.as_view(),name='delete')
]
```

in newpost_details.html

```
 <a href="{% url 'blogapp:delete' pk=draft_view.pk %}"> <input class="btn btn-danger" type="text" name="" value="Delete"> </a>
```

in newpost_confirm_delete.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="" value="Confirm Delete">
    <a href="{% url 'blogapp:drafts' pk=newpost.pk  %}"><input class="btn btn-primary"  type="text" name="" value="Cancel"></a>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your view `DraftsDeleteView` and the template that it renders.

Comment: AbdulAzizBarkat I have edited. now you can see DraftsDleteView in views.py and template that it renders is newpost_confirm_delete.py

Answer (score 0):

Just uncomment and edit this line in urls.py

```
path('drafts/<int:pk>/',views.DraftsEditView, name=‘drafts’),
```